# Animated network graph with javascript / react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, d3.js, css-animations

I am using React

I want to animate a series of chronological events occurring in network graph.
Requirements as follows;

1. Network graph displayed is statically drawn (i.e: nodes and edges never change)
2. Given a dynamic list of chronological events (which come from an api), animation shows the nodes in the network highlighted one after another for the given times
3. There is a play/pause slider to play/pause and scroll through the animation
4. The events are shown in a table and table rows can be clicked on to jump to the time in the animation they occured
5. Would also be nice to be able to play animation at 2x, 4x ... speeds

[image: Example]

#### My questions

- How can this be implemented in react?
- Is there any library that can help me with this?
- Or any similar project which may be a good starting point?

#### My thoughts

I am totally open to any open source solution as long as it can be implemented using react.
I am thinking of using [d3](https://d3js.org/) (though I have no prior experience). The following examples seem somewhat similar to what I want to do.

- http://www.claudiobellei.com/2017/02/04/viznetworks/
- https://observablehq.com/@stwind/raft-consensus-simulator